# JAVA - modernizing data interaction against legacy system

Tags: jdo, jpa-2.0

I would very much like to upgrade a legacy system currently using JSP and a home-grown web framework that is almost 10 years old.  The web system (data entry and reporting) shares a database with a legacy PowerBuilder (non-web) system that does most of the data processing.  Much - 90% or more - of the data processing business logic exists in stored procedures and it is mandated that the web system use only stored procs. Most of the procs used by the web system are fairly simple, just returning accounts, lists, and entering data into a dozen of so tables. From a lot of web reading I am lead to believe that a JPA2 implementation would not be a good choice for this because of the stored procs usage requirement.  I also find a few suggestions that JDO would be acceptable but many who bash JDO.   Should I use a JPA implementation?  What is the 'stored proc' problem - do JPA implementations get short circuited by stored procs because they can not optimize against what they do not control?

Answer (score 0):

If you're (only) using stored procs, why would you contemplate using a persistence API ? No standardised persistence API has inbuilt support for stored procs, not JPA nor JDO. You can use stored procs with implementations of those specs.

JDO is a datastore agnostic API, and JPA is for RDBMS only. Yes, there are people who "bash" JDO, but then they have political motives not technical.